# string v equal to left and right rotation

Tags: c++, string, algorithm

L(X)  is defined as shifting all characters of string X one step towards left and moving the first character to the end.
R(X) is defined as shifting all characters of string X one step towards the right and moving the last character to the beginning.
For example, L("abcd") = "bcda" and R("abcd") = "dabc"

I want to find out whether there exists a string V of the same length as S such that both L(V)=S and R(V)=S holds.

questio is basically when left rotation and right rotation of a string is equal.
for smaller size of string , my logic is ok . I can't able to decode the logic for bigger size of string.

Comment: I don't see why the logic would be any different for large strings. Please share your algorithm, and the code you have written.

Comment: @cigien for string "ab", it is possible , for "aaaa" it is possible , for "abcd" it is not possible. How to generalise the thing ?

Comment: "yes there exists such a string"

Comment: @MooingDuck i think all character should be equal or string of size 1 and 2 ,is possible

Comment: otherwise not possible

Comment: @sushan: "abababababab"

Answer (score 3):

Note that L(R(x)) = R(L(x)) = x. That is, R and L are inverses of each other. Verify for yourself that L(V) = R(V) = S always holds if and only if S = R(R(S)).

So that is your logic to check. Note that you don't actually have to perform the rotation, you can simply check whether `S[i] == S[(i+2)%n]` where *n* is the length of your string.

Comment: @orip means I have to check whether original string and reverse of it are equal or not. if equal , then possible, otherwise not possible.

Comment: @sushan I never said anything about reverse. Please re-read my answer.

Comment: @orip okk sir, now i got it . Thanks